# Table content is movable and cells are extending beyond table border

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a dynamic prototype to construct a table. It works fine with less cells but when the cells increase, they extend beyond the table border. Secondly, I can move the table content up and down in the table. Any idea which settings can I change to prevent this?

Comment: Check properties [clipsToBounds](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds) and [isScrollEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619395-isscrollenabled)

Comment: Both are set. I don’t want my content to move , just scroll.

Comment: I see this movement after Xcode upgrade

Comment: Ok, so move does not mean scroll. What do you mean with move? Take a loot at [bounces](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces)

Comment: Thanks, I ll check and revert.